# How to get access to AngularJS in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Recently I have begun to integrate AngularJS in project. 
Before I have written many prototypes and single functions in JavaScript, for example (Node.js + socket.io functionality).

Today I a have trouble communicating AngularJS with clear JavaScript:

**JS:**

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
     showSystemMessage();
}

function showSystemMessage(message) {
     // Increment here AngularJS $scope.messagesCnt++ ?;
}
```

**AngularJS:**

```
.controller('MessagesController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.messagesCnt = 0;
}])
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{messagesCnt}}</div>
```

Please, attention to method: `showSystemMessage()`

Comment: are you getting any errors? is the `showSystemMessage()` defined in the angular file? else it won't have access to `$scope`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your socket listener code inside controller

```
function appcontroller($scope){

   socket.on('message', function (data) {
    showSystemMessage();
   }

   function showSystemMessage(message) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
      // Increment here AngularJS $scope.messagesCnt++ ?;
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, You should follow what @Yaseer has said, but i see, that you're using Socket IO native implementation [No angular Wrapper around].

Hence, you have two solutions :

1. Use [Angular Socket IO](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)
2. Access Angular Controller from the native javascript :

For this you must have an element with an identifier ID. then you can use the id to access the associated scope.

```
angular.element("#your-identifier-id-here").scope().messagesCnt++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you function `showSystemMessage` is outside the controller scope, there is no way you can update the scope variable `messagesCnt`. (There are but not straight forward.)

Instead this function of yours should reside in an angular service instead, and then on whatever event you want you could broadcast a message from your service to your controller to update its count value.